# How to get each cell from PHPExcel Laravel result?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel, import-from-excel

Im importing excel file with laravel phpexcel, it works fine, but i need to get just the first cell of each row wich is telephone column, this is my code,

```
public function importar()
{ 
    $path = 'public/excel/excelinvitaciones.xlsx';
    Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(250, function($results)  
    {
            $invitacion = new PuertoInvitacion();

            for ($i=0; $i <= count($results); $i++) 
            {  

                $arrayInvitacion = ["idpuerto" => "1" , "telefono" =>  $results[$i][0]];
                $invitacion->crearNueva($arrayInvitacion);  

            } 
    }); 
}
```

the excel file looks like this

```
A1         
   416723123  
   414123723  
   412123123
```

Its just saving [414123723]

```
id   idpuerto  telefono  
1      1         [414123723]
```

Im new at this,  i can't undestand how i have to handle $results to get just that cell information, thank you.

Comment: I don't know the library but, knowing the command chunk, I expect that $results is an array of array with 250 values, when the last one will have less then 250. When you're using `$results[$i][0]`, you're not iterating on the values but only by the lines on your chunk.

Comment: That's right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, $result is an array of arrays so named A1 on excel like "telefono" so i can access this way

```
     Excel::load('excel.xlsx', function($results) 
    {

        $r = $results->toArray(); 
        $invitacion = new PuertoInvitacion(); 
        for ($i=0; $i <= count($r); $i++) 
        {  
            Log::info( $r[0][$i]['telefono']);                
            $arrayInvitacion = ["idpuerto" => "1" , "telefono" =>  $r[0][$i]['telefono']];
            $invitacion->crearNueva($arrayInvitacion);  

        }   

    });
```